# Screenutill giving error after successful pub get

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have successfully pub get the screenutill package from pub.dev but it is still giving error.[image]

I shared a problem related to flutter screen utill package and expect solution from developers.

Comment: Actually you should close your editor and open it again if some package imports are not showing up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to scroll up in your terminal,sometimes errors in terminal not showing at bottom.

Otherwise, follow these steps:

1. Run command `flutter clean`
2. Run command `flutter pub upgrade`
3. Run command `flutter pub get`

If errors happen comment so I can help you.

Answer (score -1):

**First**, make sure that all of your code's brackets are closed properly. One missing or extra bracket can cause errors like the one you are experiencing.

**Once you've checked your code**, if you are still experiencing issues with the screen_util package, you can try running "flutter clean" in your terminal to clear any cached data, and then run "flutter pub get" again to ensure that your dependencies are installed correctly.

**It's also important** to make sure that you are importing the package correctly and following its documentation to use it properly in your code.

***I hope this helps you solve your problem!***